# How do I delete multiple rows from a table on Backand?

Tags: api, delete-row, backand

Back& API allows to remove only with an ID. How do I delete multiple rows from a table on Backand by the values of other columns?
I need to remove by other fields of the table, not by ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete multiple rows use the following REST configuration. The headers should contain your Authorization bearer and AppName

```
url: https://api.backand.com/1/bulk
body: [
    {
        "method":"DELETE",
        "url":"https://api.backand.com/1/objects/YOUR_OBJECT_NAME/OBJECT_ID1"
    },
    {
       "method":"DELETE",
        "url":"https://api.backand.com/1/objects/YOUR_OBJECT_NAME/OBJECT_ID2"
    }
]
```

e.g.

```
[
    {
        "method":"DELETE",
        "url":"https://api.backand.com/1/objects/news/2"
    },
    {
        "method":"DELETE",
        "url":"https://api.backand.com/1/objects/news/3"
    }
]
```

headers should look like this

```
Headers:{"Authorization": Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN, "AppName": YOUR_APP_NAME}
```

Comment: With the SDK its Backand.apiUrl()

Comment: I got it from backand

Comment: I need to remove by other fields of the table, not by ID

Comment: you can delete only by Id, a workaround is to query all these ids and loop the delete call for each or construct the above JSON with these id's, you can do it once in a server side action